# Select single row result based off of column content

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement which returns quite literally thousands of results in a case where I only require one result per "unit"

table

```
LID     unitnumb    lat         long           time          unitid  shift         unit  timeon               timeoff           crew1       crew2   care  onduty  randid
226733  cgrausam    36.7929227  -76.1340058 2014-11-28 21:41:51 388 pathfinderKZ,CH 22  2014-11-18 09:38:54 2014-11-18 09:38:54 kzavocki    cgrausam    NULL    1   IdXENPgZ
226730  kzavocki    40.6324391  -74.4208074 2014-11-28 21:41:43 301 pathfinderKAT   22  2014-10-27 14:28:02 2014-10-27 14:28:02 kzavocki    admin   NULL    1   gIahPbib
226732  kzavocki    40.6324391  -74.4208074 2014-11-28 21:41:43 409 pathfinderKAT   22  2014-11-21 10:33:32 2014-11-21 10:33:32 kzavocki    admin   NULL    1   JFASXDXC
226735  kzavocki    40.6324391  -74.4208074 2014-11-28 21:41:43 214 Rover-Kathy     26  2014-10-07 08:47:19 2014-10-07 08:47:19 kzavocki    admin   NULL    1   CLJSZXeW
```

I have a select statement which returned these results which is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM gpstracking g 
LEFT JOIN units u 
ON g.unitnumb = u.crew1 OR g.unitnumb = u.crew2 
WHERE u.onduty = 1 and time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

currently this select statement does exactly what I want EXCEPT I only want 1 result per "unit" and I want the result to be the most recent based off of "time" 
so Ideal results would be

```
226733  cgrausam    36.7929227  -76.1340058 2014-11-28 21:41:51 388 pathfinderKZ,CH 22  2014-11-18 09:38:54 2014-11-18 09:38:54 kzavocki    cgrausam    NULL    1   IdXENPgZ
226735  kzavocki    40.6324391  -74.4208074 2014-11-28 21:41:43 214 Rover-Kathy     26  2014-10-07 08:47:19 2014-10-07 08:47:19 kzavocki    admin   NULL    1   CLJSZXeW
```

from the above - how do I modify that select statement to only display the single results from each "unit"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use variables:

```
select *
from (select *,
             (@rn := if(@u = u.unit, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := u.unit, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from gpstracking g LEFT JOIN
           units u
           on g.unitnumb = u.crew1 or g.unitnumb = u.crew2 CROSS JOIN
           (select @u := '', @rn := 0) vars
      where u.onduty = 1 and time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
      order by u.unit, time desc
     ) ut
where seqnum = 1
order by time desc;
```

Comment: while this is now returning 86 results instead of 1000's it is still resulting in many repeats of the same "unit"  I don't understand the process of variables - however the row I want unique is u.unit

Comment: @JamesStafford . . . It is easily modified.  I thought `unitnumb` was what you wanted to be unique.